# Producing variable length ByteArrays through C++ for AIR Native Extensions

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, air

For the following C++ and ActionScript3 code, my AIR application crashes when the `getBytes2` method is called. Why is this happening? Solution suggestions would be appreciated.

C++ Code:

```
FREObject getBytes2(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[])
{
    FREObject result;
    FREByteArray actualBytes;

    FREAcquireByteArray(argv[0], &actualBytes);
    uint8_t* nativeString = (uint8_t*) "Hello World from C++"; 
    memcpy(actualBytes.bytes, nativeString, sizeof(nativeString));

    FREReleaseByteArray(&actualBytes);

    FRENewObjectFromBool(1, &result);
    return result;
}
```

ActionScript3 Code:

```
    public function getBytes2():ByteArray {
        var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        this._ExtensionContext.call("getBytes2", ba);
        ba.position = 0;
        return ba;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [FREImageProcessor.cpp](https://github.com/magicalhobo/FREImageProcessor/blob/master/FREImageProcessor/FREImageProcessor/FREImageProcessor.cpp) for a working example of dynamically setting the length.  Basically you set the length the same way you would in ActionScript.

```
FREObject length;
FRENewObjectFromUint32(sizeof(nativeString), &length);
FRESetObjectProperty(argv[0], (const uint8_t*) "length", length, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any particular error or crash message?    Which IDE are you using -- is it possible to attach the debugger on that process?  I would put my money on the crash being during the memcpy function...

My only though it that while you are sending the string, you are not copying the null terminator from the string to your BA.  I don't think that should matter however (you may experience extracting the data on the AS3 side, but that shouldn't cause an issue).

Comment: I'm not getting any error, the AIR Debugger just freezes after ~1 second. For the AS3 side of the native extension and the sample AIR application I'm using Flash Builder 4.6. For the C++ side I am using VS2010. I am able to attach debuggers. I am wondering why this occurs since the code I am using is almost identical to the code you used on as3-arduino-connector...

Comment: The error is indeed due to the memcpy function and it seems to occur when the input bytearray is smaller than the resulting bytearray, but with that logic as3-arduino-connector would crash too...

Answer (score 0):

There were actually some people reporting similar issues when they were getting the byteArrays.  I have a kludgy fix I haven't posted in the ArduinoConnector code for it yet.  Pretty much involves seeding a 4096 byte byteArray on the AS3 side and sending that in.  I also tried by just creating a new byteArray in the c side with similar results.  According to the AIR engineers, we shouldn't have this problem, but I don't know if they accounted for how the memcpy function works.